# VisualForce Page onKeyup javascript not working after SLDS styling

Tags: javascript, slds

I have a VFP that I migrating to Ligntning using `<apex:slds/>`.
I have a js validate function onKeyUp() for an input Text. I know the javascript needs to be handled differently in such scenario. Can anyone poiint me in right direction? 
I am still learning to use SLDS styling and need this to work.

Following is my code:

Old code was:

```
<apex:inputText id="myId" value="{!selectTerm}" tabIndex="1" maxlength="255" onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
```

Which is changed to:

```
<div class="slds-form-element__control">
 <input type="text" class="slds-input" id="myId" value="{!selectTerm}"  onkeyup="myFunction()" />
  </div>
```

The function is basically for validating the user input for minimum number of characters and such things. Is there any other way I can achieve this? I think I can't use the JS controller when it's not a lightning component. Please suggest.

Comment: Are you still in Visualforce, or are you moving to a component?

Comment: Still in Visual Force. We don't want to move to components as yet. As a intermediate step we are migrating the existing VF pages to lightning using <apex:slds/> and using SLDS style where ever required.

Comment: Have you tried `<apex:page lightningStylesheets="true" ...` without modifying the page content?

Comment: since lightningsheets attribute is in beta and no offiial word on when will it be available, my company doesn't want to use it.:(